# Silverstripe 3 - Converting a PHP multidim array to something a template can loop

Tags: php, silverstripe

Tried various combinations of ArrayList and ArrayData for this, but no luck. Google only shows me very simple arrays being converted. Like [this](https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/data-model-questions/show/102645)

Here is my simplified array:

```
$locations = [
    'Venue' => [
        [
            'Name' => 'ANZ Events Centre',
        ]
    ],
    'Hotels' => [
        [
           'Name' => 'Pullman Hotel',
        ],
        [
           'Name' => 'Mercure Hotel',
        ]
    ]
]
```

And this is what I want to do in my template:

```
<% if $Locations %>
    <% if $Locations.Venue %>
        <% loop $Locations.Venue %>
            $Name
        <% end_loop %>
    <% end_if %>
<% end_if %>
```

I can't make much sense of what ArrayList does, as it adds a numerical key to every record I add to it. But this is the last incarnation of me trying to convert this into something the template can loop:

```
$templateArrayList = ArrayList::create();
foreach($locations as $type => $group) {
    $groupArray = [];
    foreach($group as $location) {
        $groupArray[$type][] = ArrayData::create($location);
    }
    $groupArrayData = ArrayData::create($groupArray);
    $templateArrayList->push($groupArrayData);
}
```

What have I got wrong here?

Comment: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/model/lists/

I would also check locations.length and venue.length as if the group array is empty it still might result in true. I'll take a look and see if I can  answer this shortly.

Comment: Let me get this straight you have your array ( simplified array ) and your converting it to an ArrayList for the template. Is that correct?

Comment: @DanielTate Yes. I have just found the solution after getting my head around ArrayData and ArrayList. See Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer fiddling with various combos of ArrayList and ArrayData and will leave here for future searches.

Easiest way this works out in my mind is that Associative arrays (such as the Venue/Hotel group keys, and the Name keys in the data elements) are ArrayData. Non-associative arrays (such as the collection of two hotel arrays) are ArrayList.

With that in mind, here is my working code:

```
foreach($locations as $type => $group) {
    $groupArray[$type] = ArrayList::create();
    foreach($group as $location) {
        $groupArray[$type]->push(ArrayData::create($location));
    }
    $groupArrayData = ArrayData::create($groupArray);
}

$data = [
    'Locations' => $groupArrayData
];

return $data;
```